# Reversing shell-style brace expansion

Tags: arrays, shell, brace-expansion

[Brace expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) takes a pattern and expands it. For example:

```
sp{el,il,al}l
```

Expands to:

```
spell spill spall
```

Is there an algorithm (potentially with a JavaScript implementation) to do the reverse in a way that minimizes the constructed string?

i.e., take in an array `[spell spill spall]` and return a string `"sp{e,i,a}ll"`

Comment: Why not `{spell,spill,spall}`? What about `{s}{p}{e,i,a}{l}{l}` What about `{spe,spi,spa}{ll}`? What about `sp{e,i,a}ll`? I think identifing common patterns in an array of strings and searching for an "optimal" (optimal how? in what way?) representation of the uncommon patterns in such strings using such shell expansion form, this is a very broad topic. What have you tried?

Comment: Good point, I have updated the question to indicate minimal resulting string as the optimization goal. I have currently tried creating an expander, then brute-forcing groups of characters at similar depth in the string, but the runtime explodes with longer strings.

Comment: You can probably create [a trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (yes, with the 'i') to make matching prefixes quicker to find. You can also do the same with a trie for the string in reverse to make matching suffixes quicker to find. This will cut down on the work finding candidates.

Comment: It should also be noted that the curly braces add one character (opening curly brace) and each alternative in curly braces adds another character (the character just after, either comma or closing curly brace). This can be used to find the length of that potential portion of the result without wasting time creating a bunch of intermediate strings and taking their length.

Comment: The answer you have accepted doesn't work with the example `[spell spill spall]` you provided in your question.

Comment: Good point, I have reverted to your answer as the accepted answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimizing the resulting string can be done in many different ways, but since you mention Bash, I'll choose the Bash way which is not the most optimized one.

Yes, there is a Bash way! Bash creators have included it as the readline command `complete-into-braces`. When using Bash interactively, if you hit <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> (which is either <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>-then-<kbd>{</kbd> on my machine), all possible completions are grouped into one single brace expansion.

```
$ echo /usr/
bin/     games/   include/ lib/     local/   sbin/    share/   src/  

$ echo /usr/{bin,games,include,l{ib,ocal},s{bin,hare,rc}}
```

Above, the first time I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to show all possible completions, and the second time I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>{</kbd>.

Back to your question: you are looking for an algorithm. Obviously you may find something in [Bash source code](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). The function you are looking for is [`really_munge_braces()` in `bracecomp.c`](https://github.com/ecvi/bash/blob/ae339e9c3c855a2bbd8f8667d4cf2999e3f06bfa/bracecomp.c#L66)

Comment: Fantastic! Quite a thorough answer, with a thoughtful link to the source code.

Comment: @ElleFie I forgot to add that the first parameter to `really_munge_braces()` is a *sorted* array (it is sorted in the calling function `hack_braces_completion()`)

Answer (score 1):

As requested in the original question, [node-brace-compression](https://github.com/bahamas10/node-brace-compression) contains a JavaScript implementation. E.g.

```
var compress = require('brace-compression');
var data = [
  'foo-1',
  'foo-2',
  'foo-3'
];

console.log(compress(data));
// => "foo-{1..3}"
```

Comment: Works only with sequences `{m..n}`